# Compute the kth element in spiral order for an m x n 2D array A in O(1) time

Tags: python, algorithm

Compute the kth element in spiral order for an m x n 2D array A in O(1) time.

For example...

```
A = [[1,  2,  3,  4],
     [5,  6,  7,  8],
     [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

The spiral order is `1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 12, 11, 10, 9, 5, 6, 7`.

If `k = 5`, the function returns `12`.

The closest solution I found was to check if `k` exists in the perimeter of `A`. If not, recursively call the function without the perimeter and subtract the perimeter length from `k`. Time complexity increases with the size of `A` (more perimeters to drop). Is there a way to go about this in O(1) time?

Comment: Try out a few different values for `k` and see what index you need to get. Then see if you can turn those results into a function of `k` and the dimensions of your matrix. Hint: It is possible in O(1) time.

Comment: Hint2: It is more of a mathematical challenge than a programming one.

Answer (score 4):

To derive your needed computation, try starting with a larger matrix, such as 10x7.  This will let you observe the overall effects for a couple of laps before the end cases bite you.

First, note the extent of each lap (one revolution about the matrix).  Each direction has an ever-decreasing quantity of steps, compared to the previous lap.  In the 10x7 case, you start just outside the matrix.  Then you take (10-0) steps right, (7-1) steps down, (10-1) steps left, and (7-2) steps up.  Thus, lap 1 has a length of 4 steps less than the perimeter.

You've now chopped off 2 units in each direction, and you're again just to the left of the remaining 8x5 matrix.  You take (10-2) steps right, (7-3) steps down, ... you get the idea.  Each lap is 4 units shorter than the previous, until you finally consume the shorter dimension entirely (i.e. no more elements).

Now, the problem divides into two steps:

- Determine which lap contains element `k`
- Determine where element `k` is within that lap.

Each of these is an **O(1)** computation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a 10x7 (mxn) matrix, in which we get 30 elements for the the outer ring, the next outer ring would have 22 elements, then 14 elements, and the most inner ring has the remaining elements. The number of elements per ring is given by 2 x (m - (1 + (2 x (r-1))) ) + 2 x (n - (1 + (2 x (r-1))) ), for the rth ring.

Save from the most inner ring, the difference between the number of elements of each adjacent ring is 8 elements. If we want to know the number of elements of the current ring plus all the other previous ones, we get an [arithmetic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum).

The sum of all the elements until a given r is given by sum = (r(a1 + ar)) / 2, being a1 = 2(m-1) + 2(n-1), ar = 2 x (m - (1 + (2 x (r-1) ))) + 2 x (n - (1 + (2 x (r-1) ))). For this effect, this sum represents the lower bound of k in a given ring, so we will consider k as the sum. If we solve the equation in relation to r, using the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) to disentangle the final polynomial, we reach r = math.floor((-(m + n) + math.sqrt((m+n)**2 - 4*k)) / (-4))

Now we can know in which ring the kth element is, and also know the number of elements leading up to this ring. That is the base of the below algorithm.

The rest is working with these two pieces of information to work out an offset and figure out where that offset falls in the ring (top, right, bottom or bottom portion)

This algorithm has O(1) time complexity.

*Note that the algorithm below computes the x and y on the array for a given k, m and n, which is the core part of this problem. Getting the array item from these coordinates is trivial from here.*

```python
import math

def kth_element_spiral(k: int, m: int, n: int):
    first_ring_max = 2 * (m-1) + 2 * (n - 1)

    ring, ring_start_elements = None, None

    if (k < first_ring_max):
        ring = 0
        ring_start_elements = 0
    else:
        ring = int(math.floor((-(m + n) + math.sqrt((m+n)**2 - 4*k)) /(-4)))
        ring_start_elements = int((ring * (first_ring_max + 2 * (m-(1 + 2*(ring - 1))) + 2 * (n-(1 + 2*(ring - 1))))) / 2)

    offset = k - ring_start_elements

    width = (m - ring*2) - 1
    height = (n - ring*2) - 1

    if (offset <= width): # top
        x = ring + offset 
        y = ring
        return (x, y)
    elif (offset <= width + height): # right
        x = m - ring - 1
        y = ring + (offset - width)
        return (x, y)
    elif (offset <= width + height + width): # bottom
        x = width - (offset - width - height)
        y = n - ring - 1
        return (x, y)
    else: # left
        x = ring
        y = height - (offset - width - height - width)
        return (x, y)


# Some test cases    
for i in range(10*6):
    print(i, kth_element_spiral(i, 10, 6))

for i in range(7*5):
    print(i, kth_element_spiral(i, 7, 5))

for i in range(9*6):
    print(i, kth_element_spiral(i, 9, 6))
```

Gist available at https://gist.github.com/lopespm/a5e6552451227f1ea04579e7ec750c4d

Answer (score 0):

Using Pedro's base code and some modifications for calculating total elements using arithmetic sum, below is my take:
I simplified the formula for calculating sum of AP:

```
"""
T1 = 2m + 2n - 4
Tr = 2m + 2n -8r + 4 #r here is the ring
Sr = (T1 + Tr)r/2 #sum of progression till ring r
Solving:
Sr = r(2m+2n-4+2m+2n-8r+4)/2
Sr = r(4m +4n -8r)/2
Sr = -4r^2 + (2m +2n)r #this is quadratic equation analogous to ax^2 + bx + c
Since Sr is lower bound of k, lets solve it with respect to r and k
-4r^2 + (2m +2n)r <= k
-4r^2 + (2m +2n)r - k <= 0
r = floor((-(m + n) + sqrt((m+n)^22 - 4*k)) /(-4))
"""

def kth_element_spiral(A, m, n, k):#k here starts with 1
    """
    inputs: A: array, m: rows, n: columns, k: position
    output: Array element returned for position k
    """
    if k==0:
        return(-1,-1)

    first_ring_max = 2*m + 2*n - 4
    ring, ring_start_elements = None, None #ring: rings elapsed to reach position k
    if (k < first_ring_max):
        ring = 0
        ring_start_elements = 0
    else:
        ring = int(math.floor((-(m + n) + math.sqrt((m+n)**2 - 4*k)) /(-4)))
        #arithmetic sum to find out how many elements covered in ring, ring-1 , .. 0
        ring_start_elements = int(-4*(ring**2) + 2*ring*(m+n))
    offset = k - ring_start_elements

    #rows left in current ring, logic: after every ring top and bottom rows removed
    mod_m = (m - ring*2)
    # columns left in current ring, logic: after every ring left and right rows removed
    mod_n = (n - ring*2)

    if (offset <= mod_n): # top row in the current ring
        x = ring
        y = ring + offset - 1
    elif (offset <= mod_n + mod_m - 1): # rightmost column in the current ring
        x = ring + offset - mod_n
        y = n - 1 - ring
    elif (offset <= mod_n + mod_m - 1 + mod_n - 1): # bottom row in the current ring
        x = m - 1 - ring
        y = ring + mod_n - 1 - (offset - (mod_n + mod_m - 1))
    elif offset <= mod_n + mod_m - 1 + mod_n - 1 + mod_m-1: # leftmost column in the current ring
        x = ring + mod_m - 1 - (offset - (mod_n + mod_m-1 + mod_n - 1))
        y = ring
    else:
        return(-1, -1)#not found
    return A[x][y]   

 # some test cases
for i in range(1,10):
    print(i, kth_element_spiral([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]],3, 3, i))
for i in range(1,9):
    print(i, kth_element_spiral([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]],2, 4, i))
for i in range(1,5):
    print(i, kth_element_spiral([[1], [2], [3], [4]], 4, 1, i))
```